# R data.table weird value/reference semantics

Tags: r, data.table

(This is a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62740267/is-r-data-table-documented-to-pass-by-reference-as-argument).)

Check this toy code:

```
> x <- data.frame(a = 1:2)
> foo <- function(z) { setDT(z) ; z[, b:=3:4] ; z } 
> y <- foo(x)
> 
> class(x)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
> x
   a
1: 1
2: 2
```

It looks like setDT did change x's class, but the addition of data did not apply to x.
What happened here?

Comment: At least some elements of the same question have been discussed here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4589

Comment: `z` is a reference to `x` until `setDT`. So `setDT` is applied to `x`. If you change `z` like in `foo <- function(z) {z$b <- 3:4; setDT(z); z }` `z` is no longer a reference to `x` and `setDT` does not change `x`. See output of: `foo <- function(z) {print(address(z)); z}; address(x); y <- foo(x); address(y)`

Comment: Or try: `x <- data.frame(a = 1:2); y <- x; setDT(y); class(x)`

Comment: @GKi Would be interesting if you expanded that answer to include the relevant vocabulary and logic (why this works like this).

Comment: @sindri_baldur It was my post on github. I didn't get a satisfactory answer there (yet), so thought I'd try here.

Comment: @sindri_baldur It works like this, as R is not *call by value*, it is *call by reference* as long as the value is *not* changed.

Comment: @GKi setDT So why won't setDF change the class back?  Check `x <- data.frame(a = 1:2); foo <- function(z) { setDT(z) ; z[, b:=3:4] ; setDF(z) }; y<-foo(x); class(x)`

Comment: @OfekShilon At that point, when you use `setDF`, `z` was already changed. So it is no longer a reference to `x`.

Comment: @GKi `:=` operates by reference, it doesn't make a copy of `z`. Checking with `address` it looks like `setDT` is the one making a copy of `z` (which makes the behaviour even stranger)

Comment: @OfekShilon. Yes `setDT` makes the copy. I have add a wiki "Answer" showing that.

Comment: This seems relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069219/using-setdt-inside-a-function?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your function `z` is a reference to `x` until `setDT`.

```
library(data.table)
foo <- function(z) {print(address(z)); setDT(z); print(address(z))} 
x <- data.frame(a = 1:2)
address(x)
#[1] "0x555ec9a471e8"
foo(x)
#[1] "0x555ec9a471e8"
#[1] "0x555ec9ede300"
```

In `setDT` it comes to the following line where `z` is still pointing to the same address like `x`:

```
setattr(z, "class", data.table:::.resetclass(z, "data.frame"))
```

`setattr` does not make a copy. So `x` and `z` are still pointing to the same address and both are now of class `data.frame`:

```
x <- data.frame(a = 1:2)
z <- x
class(x)
#[1] "data.frame"
address(x)
#[1] "0x555ec95de600"
address(z)
#[1] "0x555ec95de600"

setattr(z, "class", data.table:::.resetclass(z, "data.frame"))

class(x)
#[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
address(x)
#[1] "0x555ec95de600"
address(z)
#[1] "0x555ec95de600"
```

Then `setalloccol` is called which calls in this case:

```
assign("z", .Call(data.table:::Calloccolwrapper, z, 1024, FALSE))
```

which now let `x` and `z` point to different addresses.

```
address(x)
#[1] "0x555ecaa09c00"
address(z)
#[1] "0x555ec95de600"
```

And both have the `class` `data.frame`

```
class(x)
#[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
class(z)
#[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

I think when they would have used

```
class(z) <- data.table:::.resetclass(z, "data.frame")
```

instead of

```
setattr(z, "class", data.table:::.resetclass(z, "data.frame"))
```

the problem would not occur.

```
x <- data.frame(a = 1:2)
z <- x
address(x)
#[1] "0x555ec9cd2228"
class(z) <- data.table:::.resetclass(z, "data.frame")
class(x)
#[1] "data.frame"
class(z)
#[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
address(x)
#[1] "0x555ec9cd2228"
address(z)
#[1] "0x555ec9cd65a8"
```

but after `class(z) <- value` `z` will not point to the same address where it points before:

```
z <- data.frame(a = 1:2)
address(z)
#[1] "0x5653dbe72b68"
address(z$a)
#[1] "0x5653db82e140"
class(z) <- c("data.table", "data.frame")
address(z)
#[1] "0x5653dbe82d98"
address(z$a)
#[1] "0x5653db82e140"
```

but after `setDT` it will also not point to the same address where it points before:

```
z <- data.frame(a = 1:2)
address(z)
#[1] "0x55b6f04d0db8"
setDT(z)
address(z)
#[1] "0x55b6efe1e0e0"
```

As @Matt-dowle pointed out, it is also possible to change the data in `x` over `z`:

```
x <- data.frame(a = c(1,3))
z <- x
setDT(z)
z[, b:=3:4]
z[2, a:=7]
z
#   a b
#1: 1 3
#2: 7 4
x
#   a
#1: 1
#2: 7
```

```
R.version.string
#[1] "R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)"
packageVersion("data.table")
#[1] ‘1.12.8’
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems like the correct answer - a discussion with data.table's author continues here:https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4589 .  Will update.

Answer (score 1):

A supplement to GKi's answer:

`setalloccol`'s location is indeed the direct culprit: it performs a shallow copy (i.e., generates a new vector of pointers to the existing data columns) and in addition allocates extra 1024 (by default) slots for additional columns. If setting the class to `data.frame` is performed after this shallow copy (either by `class(z)<-` or by `setattr`) it is applied to this new vector and not the original argument.

However.

Even after using a fixed version of setDT (with `setattr` called after `setalloccol`), it seems there is no way to get consistent behaviour. Some operations apply to the caller copy, and some don't.

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:2, b=3:4)

foo1 <- function(z) { 
  setDT.fixed(z)
  z[, b:=5]   # will apply to the caller copy
  data.table::setDF(z)
}

foo1(df)
#    a b
# 1: 1 5
# 2: 2 5
class(df)
# [1] "data.frame"
df
#   a b
# 1 1 5
# 2 2 5

foo2 <- function(z) { 
  setDT.fixed(z)
  z[, c:=5]   # will NOT apply to the caller copy
  data.table::setDF(z)
}
foo2(df)
#    a b c
# 1: 1 3 5
# 2: 2 4 5
# Warning message:
# In `[.data.table`(z, , `:=`(c, 5)) :
#  Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a (shallow) copy of the data.table so that := can add this new column by reference. At an earlier point, this data.table has been copied by R (or was created manually using structure() or similar). Avoid names<- and attr<- which in R currently (and oddly) may copy the whole data.table. Use set* syntax instead to avoid copying: ?set, ?setnames and ?setattr. If this message doesn't help, please report your use case to the data.table issue tracker so the root cause can be fixed or this message improved.
class(df)
# [1] "data.table" "data.frame"
df
#    a b
# 1: 1 3
# 2: 2 4
```

(Using the `j` argument, e.g., `z[!is.na(a), b:=6]` gives an extra dimension of weirdness which I won't go into here).

Bottom line, the data.table package took on the brave task of punching a hole in R's all-value semantics. It was pretty successful until setDT came along (BTW, in response to a SO question here). Using setDT within a function *on an argument* will probably never have consistent semantics and is almost guaranteed to get you nasty surprises.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)

x <- data.frame(a = 1:2)
y <- x                #y is a reference to x
address(x)
#[1] "0x55e07e31a1e8"
address(y)
#[1] "0x55e07e31a1e8"
setDT(y)              #Add data.table to attr of y AND x, create a copy of it and let y point to it and make y a DT
address(x)
#[1] "0x55e07e31a1e8"
address(y)
#[1] "0x55e07e7b1300"
class(x)
#[1] "data.table" "data.frame"

x[, b:=3:4]
#Warnmeldung:
#In `[.data.table`(x, , `:=`(b, 3:4)) :
#  Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a (shallow) copy of the data.table so that := can add this new column by reference. At an earlier point, this data.table has been copied by R (or was created manually using structure() or similar). Avoid names<- and attr<- which in R currently (and oddly) may copy the whole data.table. Use set* syntax instead to avoid copying: ?set, ?setnames and ?setattr. If this message doesn't help, please report your use case to the data.table issue tracker so the root cause can be fixed or this message improved.

z <- data.frame(a = 1:2)
class(z) <- c("data.table", "data.frame")
z[, b:=3:4]
#Warnmeldung:
#In `[.data.table`(x, , `:=`(b, 3:4)) :
#  Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a (shallow) copy of the data.table so that := can add this new column by reference. At an earlier point, this data.table has been copied by R (or was created manually using structure() or similar). Avoid names<- and attr<- which in R currently (and oddly) may copy the whole data.table. Use set* syntax instead to avoid copying: ?set, ?setnames and ?setattr. If this message doesn't help, please report your use case to the data.table issue tracker so the root cause can be fixed or this message improved.
```

Comment: Note that even this seems to contradict the docs: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.8/topics/setDT  says "n data.table parlance, all set* functions change their input by reference. That is, no copy is made at all,".    I suspect (by the GH discussion) only a *shallow* copy is made, but can't verify.  Anyway, does this explain the behaviour in the question?

Comment: @OfekShilon The copy is made by *R* and not by *data.table*. But the copy is made *after* data.table makes `setattr` - so in our case both `x` and `y` get the `data.table` class.

Comment: @OfekShilon Actually I think it is a **bug** in DT, because `x` claims only to be a DT, but it is not!

Comment: you mean that its `class` contains both data.table and data.frame?   This is the expected behaviour: `y<-data.table(a=1:2);class(y)`.   R's classes and inheritance are nasty - the class attr is a list of 'parents', where R should look for implementations (in order).

Comment: @OfekShilon The class attr is OK. But the internal data structure is not like a DT and so I get the warning.

Comment: Oliver discussed this at his answer to the linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62742393/89706 .  I don't think this is a bug by itself.

Comment: @Gki, to shed a little light about what `setDT()` is doing, I believe `setDT()` modifies the class by reference but only overalloates columns for the object passed to `setDT()`. Which is why you get the .internal.selfref message / the class is a data.table.